# Python Pandas: how to find rows in one dataframe but not in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have two tables: `people_all` and `people_usa`, both with the same  structure and therefore the same primary key.

How can I get a table of the people not in the USA? In SQL I'd do something like:

```
select a.*
from people_all a

left outer join people_usa u
on a.id = u.id

where u.id is null
```

What would be the Python equivalent? I cannot think of a way to translate this where statement into Pandas syntax.

The only way I can think of is to add an arbitrary field to people_usa (e.g. `people_usa['dummy']=1`), do a left join, then take only the records where 'dummy' is nan, then delete the dummy field - which seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: wouldnt a `people_all_set.difference(people_usa_set)` do the trick?

Comment: Does this work only on the index of the dataframe? I'd like the option to specify the field(s) to apply this to

Comment: @LawrenceBenson `difference` operates on indexes so it would need to be `people_all_set.index.difference(people_usa_set.index)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html

Answer (score 27):

use `isin` and negate the boolean mask:

```
people_usa[~people_usa['ID'].isin(people_all ['ID'])]
```

Example:

```
In [364]:
people_all = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : np.arange(5)})
people_usa = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : [3,4,6,7,100]})
people_usa[~people_usa['ID'].isin(people_all['ID'])]

Out[364]:
    ID
2    6
3    7
4  100
```

so 3 and 4 are removed from the result, the boolean mask looks like this:

```
In [366]:
people_usa['ID'].isin(people_all['ID'])

Out[366]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

using `~` inverts the mask

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this if you have multiple columns to check/join?

Comment: You could do a `merge` and then eliminate the rows that exist in the merged df otherwise you'd have to build a boolean condition for all the columns you want to compare but presumably when checking the multiple columns you're stating that it's unique for those columns, correct? For instance it's not a match if say col1 and col2 match but col3 does not

Comment: Yes merge is what I have been doing but it feels like a hassle. 

...I mean something like `select * from A where not exists (select * from B where A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2)`  I feel like this statement is impossible to do elegantly in pandas :(

Comment: @Pekka: You could use `mask = people_all[primary_key].isin(people_usa[primary_key]).all(axis=1)`. Then select the nonusa people with `people_nonusa = people_all.loc[~mask]`.

Comment: @Pekka I agree with unutbu in that you don't necessarily have to do everything in a one-liner and can split the statement to make it more readable

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions but I have trouble understanding your explanation. I think this discussion merit new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652718/pandas-find-rows-which-dont-exist-in-another-dataframe-by-multiple-columns
If you could make a more comprehensive explanation there I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another similar to SQL Pandas method: [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
people_all.query('ID not in @people_usa.ID')
```

or using NumPy's [in1d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) method:

```
people_all.[~np.in1d(people_all, people_usa)]
```

NOTE: for those who have experience with SQL it might be worth to read [Pandas comparison with SQL](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: Your second method returns errors for me, unfortunately. For one, the syntax is wrong since it has dot notation and square brackets. Removing the dot, it complains that the item has a wrong length.

Answer (score -2):

I would combine (by stacking) the data frames and then perform a .drop_duplicates method. Documentation found here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html