# Pandas: Find rows which don't exist in another DataFrame by multiple columns

Tags: python, join, pandas

same as this [python pandas: how to find rows in one dataframe but not in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651860/python-pandas-how-to-find-rows-in-one-dataframe-but-not-in-another)
but with multiple columns

This is the setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[0,1,1,2],
    col2=['a','b','c','b'],
    extra_col=['this','is','just','something']
))

other = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[1,2],
    col2=['b','c']
))
```

Now, I want to select the rows from `df` which don't exist in other. I want to do the selection by `col1` and `col2`

In SQL I would do:

```
select * from df 
where not exists (
    select * from other o 
    where df.col1 = o.col1 and 
    df.col2 = o.col2
)
```

And in Pandas I can do something like this but it feels very ugly. Part of the ugliness could be avoided if df had id-column but it's not always available.

```
key_col = ['col1','col2']
df_with_idx = df.reset_index()
common = pd.merge(df_with_idx,other,on=key_col)['index']
mask = df_with_idx['index'].isin(common)

desired_result =  df_with_idx[~mask].drop('index',axis=1)
```

**So maybe there is some more elegant way?**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since `0.17.0` there is a new [`indicator`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements) param you can pass to `merge` which will tell you whether the rows are only present in left, right or both:

```
In [5]:
merged = df.merge(other, how='left', indicator=True)
merged

Out[5]:
   col1 col2  extra_col     _merge
0     0    a       this  left_only
1     1    b         is       both
2     1    c       just  left_only
3     2    b  something  left_only

In [6]:    
merged[merged['_merge']=='left_only']

Out[6]:
   col1 col2  extra_col     _merge
0     0    a       this  left_only
2     1    c       just  left_only
3     2    b  something  left_only
```

So you can now filter the merged df by selecting only `'left_only'` rows

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this. You could do this in one line with `df.merge(other, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"')` but don't know if that's any better.

Comment: Personally I find too much chaining for the sake of producing a one liner can make the code more difficult to read, there may be some speed and memory improvements though

Comment: @Pekka: + to get back to original left in one line: `df.merge(other, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop(['_merge'],axis=1)`

Comment: I want to to add that merged[merged['_merge']=='left_only'] will not show the desired result unless we write to a file and then read. At least for me that's how it turned out to be. I had to write to a .csv and read into a new pandas df to see that the left_only rows.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
#get copies where the indeces are the columns of interest
df2 = df.set_index(cols)
other2 = other.set_index(cols)
#Look for index overlap, ~
df[~df2.index.isin(other2.index)]
```

Returns:

```
    col1 col2  extra_col
0     0    a       this
2     1    c       just
3     2    b  something
```

Seems a little bit more elegant...

Comment: If you set the index to those cols you can use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html#pandas.Index.difference) to achieve the same result