# How do I select where exists in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to get records of one dataframe based on the existence of matching records in another dataframe.

in SQL: `select a.* from a where exists (select * from b where b.id = a.id)`
or simply `select a.* from a join b on id`

related to [Pandas: Find rows which don't exist in another DataFrame by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652718/pandas-find-rows-which-dont-exist-in-another-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: note these are not the same, if a had one value of id=1 and b had two values of id=2 you would end up with 2 values using the join result and 1 using the `WHERE EXISTS` approach. So you are asking for two different things: a join with a filter clause, and a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the indices. As an example I'll make two dataframes (could be Series) with some index values in common, but not all:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'1':np.arange(10)}, index = np.arange(10) + 5)
b = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.arange(10)+100}, index = np.arange(10))
```

To find the values of `b` which have indices in common with `a`, you can do this:

```
b.reindex(a.index).dropna()
```

The output:

```
     b
5  105
6  106
7  107
8  108
9  109
```