# how can I 'de-merge' pandas data frames to produce 2 distinct sets

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 sets of data:

```
df1  
  'Y'  
A a  
B b  
C c  
D d  
E e  

df2  
  'Y'  
D d  
E e  
F f
```

I need to transform the first df1 to remove any data appearing in df2
I can easily do it using SQL, but that's not an option for me
The logic is `'select * from df1 where df1.Y not in (select Y from df2)'`
I can't seem to get the implementation right using merge. Any ideas?
Desired result:

```
df3  
  'Y'  
A a  
B b  
C c
```

with df2 unchanged

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe and dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651860/python-pandas-how-to-find-rows-in-one-dataframe-but-not-in-another

Answer (score 4):

You can subset `df1` with the `.isin()` method:

```
df1[~df1.Y.isin(df2.Y)]

#   Y
#A  a
#B  b
#C  c
```

Answer (score 2):

I do like [@Psidom's Pandas solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41317103/5741205).

Here is a NumPy alternative:

```
In [26]: d1[~np.in1d(d1.Y, d2.Y)]
Out[26]:
   Y
A  a
B  b
C  c
```

and yet another Pandas solution, which uses SQL-like [query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [30]: d1.query('Y not in @d2.Y')
Out[30]:
   Y
A  a
B  b
C  c
```