# Exclude rows whose column contains values that are in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2. One is the initial dataframe (data obtained from a source), the other is smaller and contains some mathematical transformation. For simplicity, they both have this layout:

```
df1:

A   B        C 
1   apple    a
2   pear     b
3   banana   c
4   berry    d
5   coconut  e
6   mango    f

df2:
A   B        C     D      E
1   apple    a     AT     14
2   pear     b     BT     DA
5   coconut  e     OT     OT
6   mango    f     MA     AP
```

Essentially, I would need another dataframe, i.e. df_excluded_values, that contains the rows that have been excluded from df2, based on the A column.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas: how to find rows in one dataframe but not in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651860/python-pandas-how-to-find-rows-in-one-dataframe-but-not-in-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `~` and `isin()`:

```
df_excluded = df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'].values)]
```

Returns the expected output for the rows, whose column 'A' values in `df1` are not present in df2's column 'A':

```
   A       B  C
2  3  banana  c
3  4   berry  d
```